# How to write Toast notification code for a simple math exercise?

Tags: android, notifications, toast

I need to configure a button with a code that takes the first two digits of a number (when clicked) (from a textbox) and adds a number to it; and then takes the 3rd and 4th digits and does somewhat the same to it and displays the result value in a toast message. The user inputs the original number to which the additions and subtractions must be done.

So far I have only done: `Toast.makeText(TimerCodeActivity.this, String.valueOf(`

*After that I am just lost*

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. What have you tried? What don't you understand? Try to explain what your thought process is and what you're struggling with.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it that you want to display the result you got in a toast, and it's not showing up in it because it's a numeric value? If so, you can display the number directly, just entering the CharSequence as `""+<yourNumericVariable>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
EditText theTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idOfTheEditText);

int digits = Integer.parseInt(theTextBox.getText().toString().subString(0,2)); // Take the first two digits 

int newnumber = digits + 4; // Add a number? Or are you trying to add like a string?

Toast.makeText(TimerCodeActivity.this, String.valueOf(newnumber), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```